# Laravel using AJAX to store data, but error because it said that the data is null

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql, laravel-5

Route

```
Route::resource('/post', 'PostController');
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post();
    $post->PostDate = $request->PostDate[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->PostDate[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE])) : Carbon::now();
    $post->PostTitle = $request->PostTitle[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE];
    $post->PostContent = $request->PostContent[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] ? $request->PostContent[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] : '';
    $post->PostSlug = $request->PostSlug[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] ? $request->PostSlug[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] : $post->PostTitle;
    $post->PostTypeID = $request->PostTypeID[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE]? $request->PostTypeID[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] : 1;
    $post->LanguageID = $this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
    $post->SEODescription = $request->SEODescription[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] ? $request->SEODescription[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] : '';
    $post->AllowComment = $request->AllowComment[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] ? $request->AllowComment[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] : 0;
    $post->SidebarLeft = $request->SidebarLeft[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] ? $request->SidebarLeft[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] : '';
    $post->SidebarRight = $request->SidebarRight[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] ? $request->SidebarRight[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] : '';
    $post->HTMLBeforeDetail = $request->HTMLBeforeDetail[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] ? $request->HTMLBeforeDetail[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] : '';
    $post->HTMLAfterDetail = $request->HTMLAfterDetail[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] ? $request->HTMLAfterDetail[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] : '';
    $post->AllowViewDetail = $request->AllowViewDetail[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] ? $request->AllowViewDetail[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] : 0;
    $post->AllowViewDetail = $request->PostExpiredDate[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->PostExpiredDate[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE])) : null;
    $post->CustomURL = $request->CustomURL[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] ? $request->CustomURL[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] : '';
    $post->IsVerified = $request->IsVerified[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] ? $request->IsVerified[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] : 0;
    $post->FigureCategoryID = $request->FigureCategoryID[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] ? $request->FigureCategoryID[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] : null;
    $post->FigureCategoryID = $request->ParentID[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] ? $request->ParentID[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE] : null;
    $post->PostedBy = Auth::user()->name;
    $post->save();

    return response()->json($post);
}
```

AJAX

```
$('#post-form').submit(function(){
    swal({
      title: 'Are you sure?', 
      type: 'info',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
      confirmButtonText: "Confirm!",
      closeOnConfirm: false,
      closeOnCancel: false
      },
        //function
        function(isConfirm){
          if(isConfirm){
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "<?php echo url('post'); ?>",
              data: $('#post-form').serialize(),
              dataType: 'json',
            })
            .done(function(data){
              if(data.id){
                  swal({
                    title: "Saved!",
                    text: "Your Post has been saved.",
                    type: "success"}, function(){
                      console.log(data.status);
                  });
                }else{
                  swal("Try again");
                }
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data){
                swal("Cancelled", "Please fill the data first.");
                console.log('Error:', data);
            });
          } else{
            swal("Cancelled");
          }
        //end function
    });
    return false;
});
```

In my migration, I am using

`$table->boolean('AllowViewDetail')->default(1);`

but, when I submit the data, there is an error:

> Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column "AllowViewDetail"
>   violates..

In my preview, the value of `AllowViewDetail` is 1, but why do I get an error like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AllowViewDetail` is being assigned twice.

You're re-assigning `PostExpiredDate` to `AllowViewDetail`.

I suspect your `PostExpiredDate` is null which is causing the error.